# Bootstrap 4 Tables (Altering vertical paddding/spacing?)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```
<table class="table table-borderless">
        TABLE STUFF
</table>
```

This is the simple Bootstrap HTML to create a table without borders. How do I then change the vertical padding, since the individual rows are quite spaced out. I would like a tighter design.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `table-sm` class for [condensed table rows](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#small-table), or use the [Spacing Utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/).

Comment: The issue is that makes it condensed both vertically and horizontally, is there any way to control the horizontal padding if I use that?

Comment: using the spacing utils